# Java Download File (Original Name)

Tags: java

I want to download to the exact file name returned from a URL. The URL does NOT contain the file name, it redirects, so don't suggest string manipulation.

I need to keep it the same file name and extension just like a web browser would download the file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833985/how-to-get-the-original-file-name-when-downloading-file-with-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the headers of the response. There will be a header that looks like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="thefilename.ext"
```

Comment: How can I do this using the URL class though?

Comment: I'm assuming you're calling openConnection on your URL object. After you do that, you can get the header fields from the URLConnection object that gives you like this: connection.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition")